# Select rows if columns meet condition

Tags: pandas, indexing, dataframe, conditional-statements, any

I have a `DataFrame` with 75 columns.

How can I select rows based on a condition in a specific array of columns? If I want to do this on all columns I can just use

```
df[(df.values > 1.5).any(1)]
```

But let's say I just want to do this on columns 3:45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) can be omited:

```
#if need from 3rd to 45th columns 
print (df[((df.iloc[:, 2:45]) > 1.5).any(1)])
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(5,10)), columns=list('abcdefghij'))
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1
1  0  2  1  2  0  2  1  2  0  0
2  2  0  1  2  2  0  1  1  2  0
3  2  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  0  0
4  1  0  0  1  2  1  0  2  2  1

print (df[((df.iloc[:, 2:5]) > 1.5).any(1)])
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
1  0  2  1  2  0  2  1  2  0  0
2  2  0  1  2  2  0  1  1  2  0
4  1  0  0  1  2  1  0  2  2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ix` to slice the columns using ordinal position:

```
In [31]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,10), columns=list('abcdefghij'))
df

Out[31]:
          a         b         c         d         e         f         g  \
0 -0.362353  0.302614 -1.007816 -0.360570  0.317197  1.131796  0.351454   
1  1.008945  0.831101 -0.438534 -0.653173  0.234772 -1.179667  0.172774   
2  0.900610  0.409017 -0.257744  0.167611  1.041648 -0.054558 -0.056346   
3  0.335052  0.195865  0.085661  0.090096  2.098490  0.074971  0.083902   
4 -0.023429 -1.046709  0.607154  2.219594  0.381031 -2.047858 -0.725303   

          h         i         j  
0  0.533436 -0.374395  0.633296  
1  2.018426 -0.406507 -0.834638  
2 -0.079477  0.506729  1.372538  
3 -0.791867  0.220786 -1.275269  
4 -0.584407  0.008437 -0.046714
```

So to slice the 4th to 5th columns inclusive:

```
In [32]:
df.ix[:, 3:5]

Out[32]:
          d         e
0 -0.360570  0.317197
1 -0.653173  0.234772
2  0.167611  1.041648
3  0.090096  2.098490
4  2.219594  0.381031
```

So in your case

```
df[(df.ix[:, 2:45]).values > 1.5).any(1)]
```

should work

indexing is `0` based and the open range is included but the closing range is not so here 3rd column is included and we slice up to column 46 but this is not included in the slice